# Как добавить копию элемента рядом с самим элементом в списке List<T> С#

Tags: c#

Такой вопрос, у меня есть программа которая, добавляет копию элемента если он пропорционален числу 3. Пытался реализовать таким образом. Но при запуске программа зависает на цикле, как решить проблему???

```
List<int> s = new <List>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
for(int i =0; i<s.Count;i++)
{
  if(s[i]%3==0)
  {
    s.Insert(i,s[i]);
  }
}
foreach(int i in s)
{
  Console.Write(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
{
  if (s[i] % 3 == 0)
  {
    s.Insert(i, s[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Супер, помогло)

Comment: @roxyash Отлично. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.